# Show that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is either $1$ or $p+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a group with $|G|=(p-1)p(p+1)$. Show that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is either $1$ or $p+1$.

Hint: Write $n_p(G)=kp+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and show that $p^2-1=(kp+1)l$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Conclude that $p$ divides $l+1$ and use this to prove the wanted conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|G|=p(p-1)(p+1)$ and $gcd(p,(p-1)(p+1))=1$. The theorem of Sylow implies that $n_p(G)$ divides $(p-1)(p+1)$.

We have $(p-1)(p+1)=p^2-1=(kp+1)l$ implies that $p^2=klp+l+1$, we deduce that $p$ divides $klp+l+1$ and $p$ divides $l+1$. $l+1=ap, l=ap-1$.
Since $l$ and $n_p(G)$ are positive, $k,\geq 0, a>0$. Suppose that $k\geq 2$,
$p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)\geq 2p(ap-1)$. Impossible since $ap-1\geq p-1$ and $2p> p+1$.

If $k=1$, $n_p(G)=p+1, k=0, n_p(G)=1$.